# New column based on random sample, with sample number from second table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have table 1 - a long table of ID's, and years. e.g.

```
ID    YEAR
 1    2010
 1    2011
 2    2010
 2    2011
 3    2008
```

etc...  There are thousands of rows, and each one is unique.

And table 2 - a small table giving years, and a number of IDs to sample.

```
YEAR    SAMPLE_NO
2008        10
2009       110
2010      1200
```

Not all of the YEARS in table 1 appear in table 2.

I need to add a binary TRUE/FALSE column to table 1, where for each YEAR a random sample are given TRUE, and the number who get TRUE are taken from the SAMPLE_NO in table 2.

I've been trying to do this using dplyr. I made a list of the years that are Table 2, and then filter to select those years. I'm stuck on how to do the next step - I think it's some combination of group_by and mutate, but can't figure out how to randomly apply the sample numbers from table 2.

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming number of rows in `table1` for each `YEAR` are always greater than equal to respective `SAMPLE_NO` in `table2` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

table1 %>%
  left_join(table2,  by = 'YEAR') %>%
  group_by(YEAR) %>%
  mutate(newcol = row_number() %in% sample(n(), first(SAMPLE_NO)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this work if there are years in table1 that are not in table2? I think they will end up as NA after the join, and then the sample number would be NA...?

Comment: What do you want to do if there are years in table1 that are not in table2 ?

Comment: Never mind, I can just change any NA's to zero. Where the years are not in table 2 all the records should be FALSE. Thanks!